# How to properly redirect a requests library response to a flask response?

Tags: python, http, flask, python-requests

I want to redirect a response from the reqeusts library as a proper flask response. I want to save the body, status code and headers, coockies. In case of an error response I want to redirect this error as a flask response too.

I tried this. But ran into an error:

```
import requests
import flask

def f():
   resp = requests.get(...)
   return flask.Response(response=resp.json(), status=resp.status_code, headers=resp.headers)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Flask's `make_response`, from its [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.make_response):

> Sometimes it is necessary to set additional headers in a view. Because views do not have to return response objects but can return a value that is converted into a response object by Flask itself, it becomes tricky to add headers to it. This function can be called instead of using a return and you will get a response object which you can use to attach headers.

Your code would have to change to:

```
def f():
    resp = requests.get(...)
    flask_resp = Response(response=resp.text)
    for key, value in resp.headers.items():
        flask_resp.headers[key] = value

    return flask_resp
```

### Update regarding cookies

The above code as is, doesn't set the cookies. From curl client I can see an error:

```
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
```

meaning some of these headers is "corrupting" the headers Flask sends back. I tried to set header only for the `set-cookie` header, i.e:

```
def f():
    resp = requests.get(...)
    flask_resp = Response(response=resp.text)
    for key, value in resp.headers.items():
        if key == 'Set-Cookie':
            flask_resp.headers[key] = value

    return flask_resp
```

and then the cookies were populated in the browser. So, some of the other headers from the `resp.headers.items()` is causing the problem. You can play with it and isolate what and why is causing the problem.

Comment: will this preserve the coockies? As far as I remember coockies are jsut headers, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Predicate plz see updated answer